# wordpress (301 redirect plugin)/ php question

Tags: php, wordpress

I am setting up a website in wordpress. the site was done by someone else. After setting up the site / database I get the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\Documents and Settings\user101\
Desktop\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\wp-301redirect\wp-301redirect.php on 
line 320
```

line 320 is the very last line of wp-301redirect.php page. I looked up what 301redirect is and it is apparently a plugin. The wp-301redirect.php page I have is exactly what the plugin [provides](http://www.searchenginepeople.com/tools/wp-301redirect.zip) (zip download). line by line.

Does anyone know what might be causing this.?

Answer (score 1):

In the default file for this plugin. line 220 has `<?` it should be changed to `<?php` to fix this error

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the last line after ?>. And generally it's advisable to not close your PHP with ?> as it's not required and prevents this from happening in the first place.

Comment: what do you advise closing PHP with if not ?> 
I can try that too

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, a function or control block is missing its matching end-brace, such as:

```
function foo() {
  //stuff
  ...

// EOF
```

OR

```
if (true) {
  ...

// EOF
```

Comment: This file is exactly like the file that comes with plugin. i doubt any block is missing a brace

Comment: I downloaded the file and ran `php -l wp-301redirect.php` on the file, and it did not find any syntax errors.  So either you accidentally munged the file, or (maybe) your PHP version is out of date and should be upgraded?